# Change the script path for ASP.NET Web Forms projects

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, scripting

I've created a new script folder into `~/Assets/scripts` and I don't want to keep the traditional folder `~/Scripts`.

It works for my manually included bundles, because I explicitly define their paths for my new folder, but I keep getting some errors because there are some embedded references (for AJAX scripts) that are still looking into `~/Scripts`. I just want to find a way to define globally my new script path to avoid this kind of problem.

The errors are:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:56906/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js`

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:56906/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js`

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply use Find/Replace i.e. find '/scripts/' replace '/assets/scripts' ?

Comment: I did it, but the framework adds new code to include AJAX scripts. In other words, what I need is to find out how to Find/Replace this path, but it is not written in any file in my project...